# How can I save uploaded image and data and use it in my website online?

Tags: database, image, storage, web-hosting

I'm creating a website which has upload image and data functionality.

I'm having trouble understanding the relation between web hosting and online databases. I've read an article that says web hosting comes with a database to store data.

Does web hosting also store image, or is there a good way store image and use it in my website?

Answer (score 1):

You can upload your image to the web server and name it using upload datetime so there won't be any duplicate and then save the file directory and the name to your database. for example : '/storage/images/20230330100001.jpg'

afterwards, you can access your image using the directory stored in your database.

Comment: images can be stored in the database rather than a file system. Depending on the web hosting you may not have any write access to the file system other than deploying the app. You could also have image uploading purely to file system with no database at all. It all depends on the specifics of what services your host provides, the programming language(s) and system(s) you use to create your site with.